# Get the geometry from the text in a label

Tags: pyqgis

I need to be able to convert the outline of label text to a polygon shapefile so I can use it with ArcGIS Online.

Can I somehow get the geometry of the text values using pyqgis?

Comment: could you clarify, do you want to trace the font glyph outlines of individual characters in the labels, and convert them to geometries? or do you want the bounding box/envelope/convex hull of the label?

Comment: I would like the font outlines of individual characters in the label so I can convert them to geometry.